# PHP if option is selected, selected option can't selected again in other chooses

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my name is Patrick and this is my first question, i'm sorry but i'm not very good in PHP. probably there are more improvements but this post is for the questions. (but improvements are also welcome)

Question:

You can choose a team of 2 monsters // The monster are selected form database

The question is: if you choose 1 monster how can i fix that you can't choose the same monster on option 2?

PHP CODE:

**Action of the 2 sumbit buttons**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}else{
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    if ($_POST['save'] == 'keuze4') {

        $fuelQuery4 = sprintf("UPDATE user_team SET `m_keuze4` = '%s' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'  ",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['option4']));
        $Result = mysql_query($fuelQuery4);
            if($Result){
            echo 'Team is aangepast!';
            }


    } elseif ($_POST['save'] == 'keuze5'){

        $fuelQuery5 = sprintf("UPDATE user_team SET `m_keuze5` = '%s' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'  ",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['option5']));   
        $Result = mysql_query($fuelQuery5);
            if($Result){
            echo 'Team is aangepast!';
            } 
    }

    echo '';}   

?>
```

**Get the monsters form database and put it in a select list**

```
<?php
 $get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_monsters WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' ORDER BY usid ASC");
$option4 = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option4 .= '<option value = "'.$row['usid'].'">'.$row['usid'].' - '.$row['monster'].' - '.$row['type'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

**Show the selected item**

```
<?php

 $k4 = mysql_query("


SELECT user_team.m_keuze4, user_monsters.usid, user_monsters.monster, user_monsters.type, user_monsters.attack, user_monsters.defense
FROM user_team
INNER JOIN user_monsters
ON user_team.m_keuze4=user_monsters.usid
ORDER BY user_monsters.type;

 ");
 while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($k4))
 {
 $k4_1 = ''.$row4['m_keuze4'].' - '.$row4['monster'].' - '.$row4['type'].' - '.$row4['attack'].' - '.$row4['defense'].'';
 }

?>
```

Option 5 is the same code as 4:

```
    <?php
 $get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_monsters WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' ORDER BY usid ASC");
$option5 = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option5 .= '<option value = "'.$row['usid'].'">'.$row['usid'].' - '.$row['monster'].' - '.$row['type'].'</option>';
}
?>

<?php

 $k5 = mysql_query("


SELECT user_team.m_keuze5, user_monsters.usid, user_monsters.monster, user_monsters.type, user_monsters.attack, user_monsters.defense
FROM user_team
INNER JOIN user_monsters
ON user_team.m_keuze5=user_monsters.usid
ORDER BY user_monsters.type;

 ");
 while($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($k5))
 {
 $k5_1 = ''.$row5['m_keuze5'].' - '.$row5['monster'].' - '.$row5['type'].' - '.$row5['attack'].' - '.$row5['defense'].'';
 }

?>
```

**The Form**

```
<form action="team.php" method="post">

 <select name="option4"> 
<?php echo $option4; ?>
</select><br><br>Keuze 4  
<?php 
 echo $k4_1;
  ?><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="keuze4"/>
</form>

<form action="team.php" method="post">
 <select name="option5"> 
<?php echo $option5; ?>
</select><br><br>Keuze 5  
<?php 
 echo $k5_1;
  ?><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="keuze5"/>
</form>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You can either use javascript and when a monster is selected in one option box, remove it from the other; or in PHP, when the form is selected, add a check to make sure that option4 isn't the same as option5. I think. Your code is very confusing, and I'm not entirely sure I've figured the logic right.

Comment: This is my first project if you see some thinks that can be done easier, please post it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php the best you can do check the option once its posted:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  if (filter_input(INPUT_POST,'option4') == filter_input(INPUT_POST,'option5')){
    echo "Sorry. You can't select the same monster twice";
  }else{
    //your db insert logic goes here
  }
}
```

It would be a good idea to also include some javascript to alert the user before they submit the form. This example uses jQuery

```
$('[name="option4"],[name="option5"]').change(function(){
   if  ($('[name="option4"]').val() == $('[name="option5"]').val()){
      alert('you already chose that monster, please choose another');
   }
});
```

**The Form**

```
<form action="team.php" method="post">

    <select name="option4"> 
        <?php echo $option4; ?>
    </select><br><br>Keuze 4  
    <?php
    echo $k4_1;
    ?><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="keuze4"/>
</form>                                 <!-- remove this line-->

<form action="team.php" method="post">  <!-- and    this line-->
    <select name="option5"> 
        <?php echo $option5; ?>
    </select><br><br>Keuze 5  
    <?php
    echo $k5_1;
    ?><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="keuze5"/>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[name="option4"],[name="option5"]').change(function () {
            if ($('[name="option4"]').val() == $('[name="option5"]').val()) {
                alert('you already chose that monster, please choose another');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Action of the 2 sumbit buttons**

```
 if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option4') == filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option5')) {
            echo "Sorry. You can't select the same monster twice";
        } else {
            if ($_POST['save'] == 'keuze4') {

                $fuelQuery4 = sprintf("UPDATE user_team SET `m_keuze4` = '%s' WHERE `id`='" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "'  ", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['option4']));
                $Result = mysql_query($fuelQuery4);
                if ($Result) {
                    echo 'Team is aangepast!';
                }
            } elseif ($_POST['save'] == 'keuze5') {

                $fuelQuery5 = sprintf("UPDATE user_team SET `m_keuze5` = '%s' WHERE `id`='" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "'  ", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['option5']));
                $Result = mysql_query($fuelQuery5);
                if ($Result) {
                    echo 'Team is aangepast!';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit** again,

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0u8vxoxq/) of js**

Comment: Can you please help my where i need to paste the code? i have tried many ways but it won't work good.

Comment: I now that your answer is correct but i don't works.

The first code of you below Action of the 2 sumbit buttons
Is the same as my code,

I see only changes below the form with the javascript but thats not working.

Comment: I wan't the best soluction is that with JS of PHP // ! I see it works (JAVASCRIPT) but you can still save if you click the error away

Comment: the best solution is to use js AND php, i edited "the form" you have to delete 2 lines to turn the forms into one form then the php should work, see above.      
 
the js is not designed to prevent the user from choosing the same option twice, only to warn them. the php will prevent it

Comment: Thank you it's almost done :), we checked the first choose how can we check the second choose?

Explain:

If choose 2 is "91", can't choose 1 not be "91"
but
conversely it work and thats is not oke

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? the php checks both, if you choose "2" in the 2nd select first, you'll get a js warning if you choose "2" in the first one after, it works either way round

Comment: You can choose 2 monsters every monster has is own "update" button. If you select the same monster you will get an error. But if you click it away and you choose as explain monster 1 "5" and click update the monster will change in 5. Then you will change the select form monster 1 tot "everything but not 5" and select the monster 2 to "5" and click on the update button form monster 2, than will update the monster also to "5" but there is only just one monster "5" how can i do if monster 1 is "5" you can't update monster 2 to "5"?